# Null Pointer in Adapters when Data Transmission INterupted

Tags: android, null, nullpointerexception, adapter

I get `null` Force Closes on my Android App when the user interrupts transmission to a data feed.  Or sometimes if the internet is slow and it seems to stall I get `null`

Here is how I handle the http code:

```
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url_select);

        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            // read content
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Then in `onPostExecute` of the `AsyncTask`, null is returned here as seen in the LogCat below:

```
adapter = new ReviewAdapter(getActivity(), r, tf); // Line 1164
```

I assume `r` is what is `null` that kills it?    (`tf` is a TrueType Font I pass in)

Here is the `r` code:

```
        for (String i : reviews) {
            r[index] = new Review(reviews.get(index),
                    datelist.get(index), userlist.get(index),
                    itemlist.get(index), ratings.get(index),
                    helpfulCount.get(index), chatCounts.get(index),
                    catlist.get(index), titlelist.get(index));
            index++;
        }
```

These `ArrayLists` are populated through `JSON` Parsing from `PHP`, etc.

So my question is:  How do I handle this popularly?  Is there away to avoid null? Or how can I gracefully throw a error rather than forceclose?

Here is Logcat:

```
02-19 12:15:12.012: E/AndroidRuntime(32116): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-19 12:15:12.012: E/AndroidRuntime(32116): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-19 12:15:12.012: E/AndroidRuntime(32116):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.init(ArrayAdapter.java:310)
02-19 12:15:12.012: E/AndroidRuntime(32116):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:128)
02-19 12:15:12.012: E/AndroidRuntime(32116):    at com.---.---.ReviewAdapter.<init>(ReviewAdapter.java:42)
02-19 12:15:12.012: E/AndroidRuntime(32116):    at com.---.---.RateFragmentActivity$ReviewFragment$ReviewTask.onPostExecute(RateFragmentActivity.java:1164)
02-19 12:15:12.012: E/AndroidRuntime(32116):    at com.---.---.RateFragmentActivity$ReviewFragment$ReviewTask.onPostExecute(RateFragmentActivity.java:1)
02-19 12:15:12.012: E/AndroidRuntime(32116):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
02-19 12:15:12.012: E/AndroidRuntime(32116):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
02-19 12:15:12.012: E/AndroidRuntime(32116):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
02-19 12:15:12.012: E/AndroidRuntime(32116):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-19 12:15:12.012: E/AndroidRuntime(32116):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-19 12:15:12.012: E/AndroidRuntime(32116):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5193)
02-19 12:15:12.012: E/AndroidRuntime(32116):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-19 12:15:12.012: E/AndroidRuntime(32116):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-19 12:15:12.012: E/AndroidRuntime(32116):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
02-19 12:15:12.012: E/AndroidRuntime(32116):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
02-19 12:15:12.012: E/AndroidRuntime(32116):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first `try` block throws an exception, you should probably just stop there and not bother with the second `try` block since `is` will potentially not be the value of `httpEntity.getContent();` if `httpClient.execute` threw an exception (which it will do in the case of a poor connection.

Why can't you just check if `r` is `null` and present an error to the user stating their connection was lost?

Comment: What is best way to check for null with `r`? I tried if (r == null) and then eclipsed said I had `dead code`.

Comment: That indicates that `r` will never be null, probably because you set it to prior to the check, e.g. `r = new Object[5]` without seeing where `r` is initialised (not shown in the code provided) I can't say any more.

Comment: I'm marking this correct, cause your answer (especially check if`r` is `null`) got me thinking about the bigger picture and you sowed that r is not null and this has nothing to do with data transmission.